# Create a tree with a label and a checkbox, detect whether its parent is checked

Tags: javafx, tree, treeview

I want to create a treeview whose item has a lable and a checkbox on the left.
I try to write as below,but when I click the button,it prints null.If I can get the graphic not null,I can get the checkbox in it.
My purpose is to konw whether the checkbox of the parent item is checked.

```
package com.qy.tth.fxgui;



import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeCheck extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(null);
    }

    private TreeItem<String> item11;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TreeItem<String> item1=new TreeItem<>("1");
        TreeItem<String> item2=new TreeItem<>("2");
        item11=new TreeItem<>("1-1");
        TreeItem<String> itemRoot=new TreeItem<>("root");
        item1.getChildren().add(item11);
        itemRoot.getChildren().addAll(item1,item2);
        TreeView<String> tv=new TreeView<>();
        tv.setRoot(itemRoot);
        tv.setCellFactory(tv1 -> new TreeCell<String>() {
            private HBox hb;
            {
                Label lable = new Label("icon");
                CheckBox cb=new CheckBox();
                hb=new HBox();
                hb.getChildren().addAll(lable,cb);
                setGraphic(hb);
            }
            protected void updateItem(String value, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(value, empty);
                if (empty || value == null) {
                    setText("");
                    hb.setVisible(false);
                }else{
                    setText(value);
                     hb.setVisible(true);
                }
            };
        });
        Button btn=new Button("show parent");
        btn.setOnAction(e->showParent());
        VBox vb=new VBox();
        vb.getChildren().addAll(btn,tv);
        Scene scene=new Scene(vb);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void showParent() {
        TreeItem<String> item1 = item11.getParent();
        Node graph = item1.getGraphic();
        System.out.println(graph);
    }
}
```

And I am not sure is it the best way to write like this,or you can give you own code completely.
My intent is just create a tree with a label and checkbox,then detect whether its parent is checked

Comment: I had deleted/undeleted my answer a couple of times (I would answer then realize a detail about your question that led to my answer being incomplete). However, as stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355147/6395627), a notification is not sent when an answer is undeleted, so I'm leaving this comment as a "notification" in case you were unaware an answer had been posted.

Comment: I honestly do not understand why you try to roll your own - first step in trying to solve a requirement _must_ be to check what core fx (or any other toolkit/framework) has to offer, than go from there if it doesnt fit your needs ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is printing `null`, I believe, is because there is no graphic set on the `TreeItem`. You set the graphic (an `HBox`) on the `TreeCell` and then later try to retrieve that graphic from the `TreeItem`.

That being said, if you are okay with the `Label` being to the *right* of the `CheckBox` there is no need to create your own `TreeCell` implementation. Instead, you can use the built in classes for this: [`CheckBoxTreeCell`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTreeCell.html) and [`CheckBoxTreeItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBoxTreeItem.html).

To set up the `TreeView` you'd use the following code:

```
TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>();
tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());
```

The static method `CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView()` assumes that the root `TreeItem` and all descendants will be instances of `CheckBoxTreeItem`. Be default, the behavior of `CheckBoxTreeCell` is:

- If no children are selected then the parent is not selected.
- If some, but not all, children are selected then the parent is indeterminate.
- If all children are selected then the parent is selected.

If you don't want this behavior you should set the [`independent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBoxTreeItem.html#independentProperty) property to `true`. This property states:

> A BooleanProperty used to represent the independent state of this
>   CheckBoxTreeItem. The independent state is used to represent whether
>   changes to a single CheckBoxTreeItem should influence the state of its
>   parent and children.
>
> By default, the independent property is false, which means that when a
>   CheckBoxTreeItem has state changes to the selected or indeterminate
>   properties, the state of related CheckBoxTreeItems will possibly be
>   changed. If the independent property is set to true, the state of
>   related CheckBoxTreeItems will never change.

---

Setting your `TreeView` up this way makes it easy to determine if a parent is selected because `CheckBoxTreeItem` has a `BooleanProperty` named `selected`.

```
CheckBoxTreeItem<?> parent = (CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) item.getParent();
System.out.println(parent.isSelected());
```

In this case, casting it okay because we know all the `TreeItem`s will be instances of `CheckBoxTreeItem`.

---

Since you also want a `Label` as a part of the `TreeCell` you can simply set the graphic of the `CheckBoxTreeItem` to a `Label` with the desired text. **Note, however, that this will put the `Label` to the *right* of the actual check box. If, as indicated in your code, you want the `Label` to the *left* of the `CheckBox` this gets a little more involved**.

Internally, a `CheckBoxTreeCell` takes the graphic of the `TreeItem` and sets it on the internal `CheckBox`; then it sets the `CheckBox` as the graphic of itself. Due to the way `CheckBox` is designed it is not simple (probably not even possible) to put the graphic/text of the `CheckBox` on the other side of the actual check box (the visual box with the check). If you want to have the `TreeItem`s graphic be on the left side of the `CheckBox` you have to use something like an `HBox` (as you were doing in your code). This can be done simpler than your attempt if you extend `CheckBoxTreeCell` rather than `TreeCell` directly.

```
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.WeakInvalidationListener;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class CustomCheckBoxTreeCell<T> extends CheckBoxTreeCell<T> {

    public static <T> Callback<TreeView<T>, TreeCell<T>> forTreeView() {
        return treeView -> new CustomCheckBoxTreeCell<>();
    }

    private final InvalidationListener graphicListener = (obs) -> updateItem(getItem(), isEmpty());
    private final WeakInvalidationListener weakGraphicListener = new WeakInvalidationListener(graphicListener);

    public CustomCheckBoxTreeCell() {
        // This again assumes that all TreeItems will actually be
        // instances of CheckBoxTreeItem
        super(item -> ((CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) item).selectedProperty());
        treeItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (oldItem != null) {
                oldItem.graphicProperty().removeListener(weakGraphicListener);
            }
            if (newItem != null) {
                newItem.graphicProperty().addListener(weakGraphicListener);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty && getTreeItem().getGraphic() != null) {
            CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) getGraphic();
            cBox.setGraphic(null);

            HBox hBox = new HBox(getTreeItem().getGraphic(), cBox);
            hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            setGraphic(hBox);
        }
    }

}
```

You would then set the cell factory like so:

```
tree.setCellFactory(CustomCheckBoxTreeItem.forTreeView());
```

**A few notes:**

1. *This relies on how `CheckBoxTreeCell` is implemented internally (specifically Java 10, but probably works with Java 8 as well). If they change the implementation in the future this could break*.
2. *This requires you to set the `Label` as the `TreeItem`s graphic rather than using it in the `TreeCell` only. If you don't want to do this, then remove the behavior that uses the `TreeItem`s graphic and replace it with an internal `Label`. This would allow you to remove the use of `graphicListener` and `weakGraphicListener`. If you want to display the graphic of the `TreeItem` as well then you would also remove `cBox.setGraphic(null)`*.
3. *I make no attempt to cache the `HBox` (or the possible `Label` if you change things based on Note #2). Instead, I just create a new `HBox` every time. It should be simple to change the code so it does cache the `HBox`, however, if you so choose*.

---

If you don't want to use `CheckBoxTreeItem` but would rather externalize whether or not an item is selected, you should look at these methods:

- [`CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView(Callback)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTreeCell.html#forTreeView(javafx.util.Callback))
- [`CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView(Callback,StringConverter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTreeCell.html#forTreeView(javafx.util.Callback,javafx.util.StringConverter))

If you still want the graphic on the *left* of the `CheckBox` you'll have to extend `CheckBoxTreeCell` here as well. The only real difference to how `CustomCheckBoxTreeCell` is implemented above is you'd have to provide a way to set the `Callback` you would have used with the above two methods to the `CustomCheckBoxTreeCell`. You can do this by exposing a constructor that takes the `Callback` or by setting the [`selectedStateCallback`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTreeCell.html#selectedStateCallbackProperty) property inside the cell factory.